# unable to invoke no-args constructor for class g.c.a.n.d.b. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem

Tags: android, gradle, release, minify

I always get this exception in login activity when I click login and I found in the logcat that the response is working as expected.
**Note:** I tried to run on the release build variant after creating a Key Store and I enabled minification

```
 release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable  true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
```

I need to know What is this minified class and how to solve this exception?